# laravel 5.1 Password::reset returns passwords.password

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have this function in controller and I can't reset password because I want to change character length to 5 digits.

```
public function postReset(Request $request)
{
  $this->validate($request, [
    'token' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required|confirmed|digits:5',
  ]);

  $credentials = $request->only(
    'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
  );

  $response = Password::reset($credentials, function ($user, $password) {
    $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
  });

  dd($response);
  switch ($response) {
    case Password::PASSWORD_RESET:
      return redirect($this->redirectPath());

    default:
      return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($request->only('email'))
        ->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
  }
}

protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
{
  $user->password = bcrypt($password);
  $user->save();
  Auth::login($user);
}
```

but it always says:

> Whoops! There were some problems with your input.

Passwords must be at least six characters and match the confirmation.

And when I added:

```
dd($response);
```

it prints:

> passwords.password

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: passwords.password means there is something wrong with your password. Probably it's less than 6 characters.

Comment: Try this `dd($request->all());`

Comment: @Ali , I did dd($request->all()); and all returns well , the password, password_confirmation and email

Comment: @Ali , yes it is less that 6 Characters and that's what I want to change , see the rules above

Comment: Are you using custom validation messages? Typically laravel would return those two validation errors as separate sentences.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because there is a hard coded validation in [`Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php).

When the `reset` method is called, it will always call [`validateReset`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9f178aa29d00ccc005c8c080b42aca7f025a09e4/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php#L158) first, which in turn calls [`validateNewPassword`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9f178aa29d00ccc005c8c080b42aca7f025a09e4/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php#L192):

```
public function validateNewPassword(array $credentials)
{
    list($password, $confirm) = [
        $credentials['password'],
        $credentials['password_confirmation'],
    ];

    if (isset($this->passwordValidator)) {
        return call_user_func(
            $this->passwordValidator, $credentials) && $password === $confirm;
    }

    return $this->validatePasswordWithDefaults($credentials);
}
```

By default, `passwordValidator` is not set. So [`validatePasswordWithDefaults`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9f178aa29d00ccc005c8c080b42aca7f025a09e4/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php#L213) will require that the password be at least 6 characters long.

You can set a `passwordValidator` using [`Password::validator`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9f178aa29d00ccc005c8c080b42aca7f025a09e4/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php#L181), which accepts a closure that must return a boolean value indicating whether the given credentials are valid. This needs to be done before `Password::reset`.

For example, changing the validator to require that the password be exactly 5 characters long would satisfy your requirements in particular.

```
Password::validator(function($credentials)
{
    return strlen($credentials['password']) === 5;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is in this class:

```
\Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker
```

and this function

```
validatePasswordWithDefaults
```

This looks a little weird that `6` is hardcoded in this function.
I guess there is probably better practice for changing that.
Maybe you could over-ride the function in your controller. Try that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
'password' => 'required|confirmed|digits:5'
```

to

```
'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:5'
```

Comment: I want it to 5 digits , not only 5 characters

Comment: If you want to use `digits` your input must be `numeric`

Answer (score 0):

### **If you want to change your Text and overwrite passwords.password then follow below steps**

First Go to **PasswordBroker.php**

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker.php
```

Go to line 35 and change here

```
const INVALID_PASSWORD =  '**any thing you want**';
```

## **Or if you want to change validation then follow below steps**

First Go to **PasswordBroker.php**

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker.php
```

Go to line 176 and change here

```
return $password === $confirm && mb_strlen($password) >= **any digit you want**;
```

Then go **ResetsPasswords.php**

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords.php
```

Go to line 69 and change here

```
'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:**degit you chose in **PasswordBroker.php****',
```

Thanks... It works